# Ruby : Trying to install gems or update the system times out Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Hi im trying to install gems but the rubygems  keeps timing out

- ruby 3.0.5p211 [ruby 3.0.5p211 [x86_64-linux]]

when :

```
gem update --system
```

i get this :

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) Net::OpenTimeout: Net::OpenTimeout (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

the output of :

```
gem update --verbose --debug --system
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_require.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_rubygems.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_rubygems.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1466 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_rubygems.rb
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_rubygems.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_webauthn_listener.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_webauthn_listener.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1466 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_webauthn_listener.rb
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_webauthn_listener.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_webauthn_listener_response.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_webauthn_listener_response.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1466 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_webauthn_listener_response.rb
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/test_webauthn_listener_response.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/utilities.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/utilities.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1466 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/utilities.rb
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/utilities.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/wrong_key_cert.pem
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/wrong_key_cert.pem
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1466 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/wrong_key_cert.pem
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/wrong_key_cert.pem
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/wrong_key_cert_32.pem
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/wrong_key_cert_32.pem
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1466 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/wrong_key_cert_32.pem
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/rubygems/wrong_key_cert_32.pem
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/test_changelog_generator.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/test_changelog_generator.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:1466 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/test_changelog_generator.rb
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:253 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12/test/test_changelog_generator.rb
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/installer.rb:950 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/ec2-user/bin
/home/ec2-user/bin/update_rubygems
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/installer.rb:950 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/plugins
Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.4.12
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.4.12
Parsing sources...
100% [14/14]  hide_lib_for_update/note.txt
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 0 seconds
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.4.12
Parsing sources...
100% [14/14]  hide_lib_for_update/note.txt
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 0 seconds
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:176 - No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /usr/share/gems/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /usr/share/gems/gems/rubygems-update-3.4.12
        /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:176:in `chdir'
        /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:176:in `install_rubygems'
        /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:289:in `update_rubygems'
        /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:93:in `execute'
        /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/command.rb:323:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/command_manager.rb:180:in `process_args'
        /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/command_manager.rb:149:in `run'
        /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:53:in `run'
        /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

looking in the internet i found out that ipv6 could be a problem
i disbled it but it keeps timing out

i hope someone can guide me to the right direction , im ot a ruby guy

Comment: Can you open https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz in a browser successfully? Or with `curl`?

Comment: yes i can, and wget works too

Comment: To clarify, are you making that curl/wget request on the same Linux system that can't connect using `gem update --system`?

Comment: yes , the same system

Comment: Try `gem update --verbose --debug --system` to look for additional information on the failure.

Comment: it's updated on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by re-insatlling Ruby using RVM
1- Uninstall Ruby :

```
~$ sudo yum remove ruby
```

Use the commands at [rvm.io](https://rvm.io/) to get the project keys and run the installation script

```
~$ gpg2 --recv-keys key1 key2
~$ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Install RVM:

```
 \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```